# I have managed to insert an image into a tkinter text widget but how to make it clickable?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-text

The following code works as far as getting the image into the text widget but I want to be able to detect when it's clicked and although that last line of code doesn't generate any errors, it doesn't work either.

```
my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = path)
tag = txtbox.image_create(txtbox.index('insert'), image = my_image)
txtbox.tag_bind(tag, "<Button-1>", on_image_click)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through the [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/text.html#M79) and could not find a way to associate tags with `image_create` directly. But there are at least two ways you could achieve this:

- Using `tag_add` to make tag:

You can use `tag_add` to add a tag to the images's index and then use it along with `tag_bind`

```
index = txtbox.index('insert')
txtbox.image_create(index, image=my_image)
txtbox.tag_add('image', index)

txtbox.tag_bind('image', '<Button-1>', on_image_click)
```

- Use `window_create` and `bind` for a widget:

Instead of using `image_create`, you can use a label to show the image and then do the binding on that label and display that label on the text widget with `window_create`

```
label = Label(txtbox, image=my_image)

txtbox.window_create(txtbox.index('insert'), window=label)
label.bind('<Button-1>', on_image_click)
```

Comment: I went for the second option as I wasn't sure how referencing by index would work in a dynamic document. Anyway second option worked a treat thanks